# Why is LogLogPlot[] slower than Plot[]?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, performance-tuning

I notice that `LogLogPlot` runs quite bit more slowly than ordinary `Plot`.  For example, consider the following two blocks of code which plots (using `Manipulate`) a region in linear scale and log-linear scale.  Notice how the log-log-scale manipulation runs more sluggishly.  Is there a way to speed up the log-log-scale version?

Linear-scale code:

```
 Mhad = 0.93827;
 Table[Tooltip[(MxSq - M^2) x/(1 - x) /. M -> Mhad, "x=" <> ToString[x]], {x, 0, .9, .1}];
 Manipulate[Plot[{1/s (s - M^2) (s - MxSq) /. M -> Mhad, %},
   {MxSq, Mhad^2, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}},
   AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Table[If[i == 1,
     RGBColor[0, 0, 0],
     {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[.001]}], {i, 1, 11}]], {{s, 50}, 1,
     400}]
```

Log-log-scale:

```
 Table[Tooltip[(MxSq - M^2) x/(1 - x) /. M -> Mhad, "x=" <> ToString[x]], {x, 0, .9, .1}];
 Manipulate[LogLogPlot[{1/s (s - M^2) (s - MxSq) /. M -> Mhad, %},
   {MxSq, Mhad^2, 100}, PlotRange -> {{.8, 100}, {.8, 100}},
   AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Table[If[i == 1,
     RGBColor[0, 0, 0],
     {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[.001]}], {i, 1, 11}]], {{s, 50}, 1,
     400}]
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the timing difference for this example. On a clean kernel, the log-log case is if anything faster according to `AbsoluteTiming`. But I replaced the `%` with an explicit label for the `Table` in the previous line - perhaps that is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
Mhad = 0.93827;
t = Table[
   Tooltip[(MxSq - M^2) x/(1 - x) /. M -> Mhad,"x=" <> ToString[x]], {x, 0, .9, .1}];
With[{s = 50}, 
  p1=Plot[{1/s (s - M^2) (s - MxSq) /. M -> Mhad, t}, {MxSq, Mhad^2,100}, 
        PlotRange -> {{.8, 100}, {.8, 100}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
        Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotStyle -> 
          Table[If[i == 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 0],
                          {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[.001]}], {i, 1,11}]]
 ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

and a similar one for `LogLogPlot` I find that `Plot` is about 2.7 times faster than `LogLogPlot`.

This is hardly surprising as the `LogLogPlot` is much more complex than the `Plot`. You can use `FullForm` to examine the underlying graphics primitives. The bytecount of these primitives have the following ratio:

```
(p2 // FullForm // ByteCount)/ (p1 // FullForm // ByteCount)
```

> 2.604100491

or take for instance the number of `List` instructions (all coordinates are in lists):

```
Cases[p1, List[___], Infinity] // Length
```

> 687

```
Cases[p2, List[___], Infinity] // Length
```

> 1202

It simply takes more coordinates to describe a curve accurately than for a set of straight lines.

One way to speed up the Manipulate may be the use of `ControlActive`, where you draw graphics with lower quality as long as the controls are being manipulated and a final one with higher quality if user-interaction stops.

```
Manipulate[
 ControlActive[
  LogLogPlot[{1/s (s - M^2) (s - MxSq) /. M -> Mhad}, {MxSq, Mhad^2,100}, 
              PlotRange -> {{.8, 100}, {.8, 100}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True,
              PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1],
  LogLogPlot[{1/s (s - M^2) (s - MxSq) /. M -> Mhad, t}, {MxSq, Mhad^2, 100}, 
              PlotRange -> {{.8, 100}, {.8, 100}}, 
              AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, Frame -> True, 
              PlotStyle -> 
                 Table[If[i == 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
                                  {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[.001]}], {i, 1, 11}]]
  ], 
  {{s, 50}, 1, 400}
]
```

which switches between

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I changed `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, `Filling` and the plotting of the background curves. Adapt to your own needs.

Comment: I don't think the number of points plotted is what matters here... For instance, if you sow the points and then use listplot to plot the same points, it is much faster. Rather, I think it has to do with _determining_ which points to plot to get the best result. It might be the internal optimization routines that take longer

Comment: @r.m. That's probably true. Note that I used the amount of primitives as a measure of the *complexity* of the plot and left it as an open question whether their *production* or their *usage* to show the plot in the FE is the cause of the slowness.